# How do I monitor all requests that programs are making on my computer including POST and GET request data

Tags: http, https

I am looking for a program that can monitor all of the http requests a program is making and also capture the POST & GET data that it is sending to the server. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on where the application you want to monitor is running. If the application is running on your computer, a popular tool that you could use to achieve this is Fiddler.

https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

If you're running an OS other than Windows, there is Beta versions for Linux and MacOS X.

There is always Wireshark, but it is an advanced network monitoring tool that may require some research in order to achieve what you want.

https://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 1):

Set up a proxy (like [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org)). Then you can review those requests in the log files.